# Enviar más de 255 letras y que muestren bien las tildes

Tags: c#

Quiero enviar un email en modo consola que supere los 255 caracteres tal como se hace en cualquier navegador.

¿Es posible hacerlo?

Aquí dejo un ejemplo con  GMail.

```
// Activar / desactivar Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras en Google.
// https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace Enviar_email_Consola_07
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Configuración ventana.
            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Probando manipulación de cadena";

            // Tamaño de la ventana, x, y.
            Console.SetWindowSize(80, 25);

            // Color de fondo.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            // Color de las letras.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

            // Limpiar pantalla y dejarlo todo en color de fondo.
            Console.Clear();

            // Visible el cursor.
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            #endregion

            // Variables.
            string usuario, contraseña, destinatario, asunto, mensaje;

            // Título del programa.
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tEnviar Correo Electrónico");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tTu correo electrónico: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                usuario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tIntroducir contraseña: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                contraseña = LeerPassword();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tDestinatario: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                destinatario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tAsunto: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                asunto = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                //----------------------------------------------
                byte[] bytes = new byte[2000]; // Nuevo tamanho máximo.
                Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput(bytes.Length);
                Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inputStream));
                //----------------------------------------------

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tMensaje: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                mensaje = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();

                MailMessage correo = new MailMessage(usuario, destinatario, asunto, mensaje);

                SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
                {
                    Port = 587
                };
                NetworkCredential credenciales = new NetworkCredential(usuario, contraseña);
                servidor.Credentials = credenciales;
                servidor.EnableSsl = true;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tEnviando correo...");
                servidor.Send(correo);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tCorreo enviado satisfactoriamente.");
                correo.Dispose();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: \n");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tNo se ha enviado el correo.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        // A la hora de introducir la contraseña, se sustituye por asterístos (*) en pantalla.
        public static string LeerPassword()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int contador = 0;

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {

                    sb.Append(cki.KeyChar);
                    if (contador < 4)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    contador++;
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            } while (true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

A parte de todo esto. Si escribo tildes, al recibir mensajes me aparecen caracteres raros. También quiero que todo lo que escribo, me aparezca bien cuando me llega el correo.

En resumen, no olvidar que si usas GAMIL hay que activar este enlace para dar permisos o no te ejará recibirlos.

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Luego cuando acabes con los ejemplos lo vuelves a desactivar por seguridad.

Cuando envíe los datos que solo lo tengo limitado a 255 caracteres, no me deja escribir más de ahí. Al ver en Gmail el mensaje, me aparecen caracteres raros, sobre todo en las tildes.

¿Hay solución para ello?

Felices fiestas camaradas.

Comment: **¿Hay solución para ello?** por supuesto, verifica el *encoding* usado al enviar el correo o incluso al leer los datos de la consola. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar lo de las tildes lo que buscas es la propiedad `MailMessage.BodyEncoding` en tu caso seria

```
correo.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Y en el caso del limite de 255 seguramente sea un limite dispuesto por google. Lo mejor en cualquier caso es hacer uso de un api de terceros como sendgrid o mailgun.

Comment: Fuciona. Mil gracias y que pase buen REyes 2022 con todos tus seres queridos. Ya conseguí el de más de 255 caracteres.